# How to test some property of model in rails without assigning all other properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, activerecord

suppose we have a model contact with the following properties

```
class Contact < ActiveRecords:Base
validates :Name, presence: true
validates :Email, presence: true
validates :Phone, presence: true
End
```

Now i want to test these properties individually ant not by using Contact.save method to check if it validates or not, as in that case i have to create a separate object to test each case.

is their any way if we check that by this property if we are getting any error or exception?

Answer (score 1):

Using [shoulda](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda) gem you be able to validate fields one by one

```
describe Contact do
  it { should validate_presence_of :Name }
  it { should validate_presence_of :Email }
  it { should validate_presence_of :Phone }
end
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers#validate_presence_of

You also be able to check whole object validation by:

```
it { expect(FactoryGirl.build(:contact)).to be_valid }
```

I suppose you're using [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to build your test data

**Update**:
Suppose you have a valid factory. Then you be able to test without shoulda gem

```
it { expect(FactoryGirl.build(:contract, :Name => '')).to be_invalid }
it { expect(FactoryGirl.build(:contract, :Email => '')).to be_invalid }
it { expect(FactoryGirl.build(:contract, :Phone => '')).to be_invalid }
```

**Update 2**:
Without factory_girl

```
it { expect(Contact.new(:Name => 'Bruce', :Email => 'email@example.com', :Phone => '+123123')).to be_valid }
it { expect(Contact.new(:Email => 'email@example.com', :Phone => '+123123')).to be_invalid }
it { expect(Contact.new(:Name => 'Bruce', :Phone => '+123123')).to be_invalid }
it { expect(Contact.new(:Name => 'Bruce', :Email => 'email@example.com')).to be_invalid }
```

Comment: is their any way we can do it without using any gem other then the default testing in rails?

Comment: Yes. I've added examples without shoulda gem

Answer (score 0):

Example using plain RSpec:

```
describe Contact do

  let(:contact_params) {
    {
      Name: 'Contact Name',
      Email: 'contact@somewhere.com',
      Phone: '0123456789'
    }
  }

  it 'is valid with valid params' do
    contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    expect(contact.valid?).to be_true
  end

  it 'is invalid when Name is missing' do
    contact_params.delete(:Name)
    contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    expect(contact.valid?).to be_false
  end

end
```